# How to get the namespace of the xml node using lmxl

Tags: python, lxml

I have a XML file like:

```
<component xmlns:xyz="some namespace">
  <import xmlns:util="tools.utils"/>
  <import xmlns:git="tools.git"/>
</component>
```

I want to know the namespace mentioned in the `<import>` node. If i use `nsmap` property of lxml, it gives dictionary of all namespaces of all the nodes.

But I want to know the namespace mentioned in the `<import>` node.

For example,
while parsing first `<import>` node, I should get `{'util' : 'tools.util'}`
while parsing second `<import>` node I should get `{'git' : 'tools.git'}`

I am using python and lxml for parsing the XML file.
Please help me

Comment: Do you have to use `lmxl` (i.e, I have a solution with `BeautifulSoup`)

Comment: Yes I have to use `lxml`. That's requirement

Comment: lxml will give nodes like {tools.util}element from which you can get the element name and namespace why exactly do you need the map? the prefixes could be anything